# Why can't getNodeValue() from org.w3c.dom parse ü, ö, ä, &c.?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am using `getNodeValue()` from `org.w3c.dom.Node` to get XML tag values. If a value contains ä, ö, ü or other special characters like them, my program just cuts off the string; e.g. "Türen" will become "T". How can I get the full values, with special chars?

I call getTextValueOfFirstChild to get the textvalue

```
 public static String getTextValueOfFirstChild(Node node, String childName)
 {
                Node node1;
                Node node2;
                if((node1 = getFirstChildNode(node, childName)) != null && (node2 = node1.getFirstChild()) != null)
                    return node2.getNodeValue();
                else
                    return null;
}

public static Node getFirstChildNode(Node parent, String name)
{
        if(parent != null)
        {
            NodeList nodelist;
            int i = (nodelist = parent.getChildNodes()).getLength();
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                Node node = nodelist.item(j);
                if(name.equals(node.getNodeName()))
                    return node;
            }

        }
        return null;
}
```

```
<carinfo>
<id>l3nqd2dpwikl</id>
<makename>Fiat</makename>
<modelname>Ducato</modelname>
<typename>HKAWA 30 L2H2 120 Multijet</typename>
<bodytype>2/3 Türen</bodytype>
<extrainfo/>
<bodycolorid/>
<intcolorid>0</intcolorid>
<logo/>
```

Comment: The problem is probably in the way you are parsing XML to create the DOM.  I expect you are not using the right character set. Please show the code ... and the first few lines of the XML file.

Comment: pls reread my comment.  You haven't supplied the code *that I asked for*.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the node in question is a text node, and only contains the first part of the string. Its next sibling will be another node containing the accented character, and that will have a sibling containing the final part of the string.

The parser is free to build nodes that way, and is presumably doing so because it encountered the accented characters as entities.

That is mostly guesswork, i should add.

In any case, rather than working with the text nodes, i would suggest getting hold of the containing element, and calling the getTextContent() method, which will go through all the children and build them up into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

If the special characters appeared in the source XML as entity references, then you may have entity nodes in the DOM as children of the element node, and your code may not be processing the entity nodes correctly: you may be assuming incorrectly that all the text is in a single text node. (This is one of the very many reasons why using DOM is such a pain - have you considered the alternatives?)

Comment: +1 for alternatives to DOM, although some of the alternatives (StAX, i think) would still pass the text in multiple chunks.

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that the OP's application is reading the XML using the wrong character set / encoding.  Unfortunately, we can't confirm this unless he/she posts the code that he uses to parse the XML to create the DOM.